# Interactive filter for HTML table with dynamically loaded data from JSON url

Tags: javascript, html, json, filter, data-retrieval

**01)** I dynamically load data from a JSON url into an HTML table.

**02)** I filter the results using a filter at the top of the page.

**03)** I load the data in the filter dynamically from the same JSON url.

**04)** I pasted the code in the snippet below (it won't load the JSON data because the url contains `https`. I created it just to make you see the code. The filter does not work here.

```js
$.getJSON(
     'http://apolosiskos.co.uk/TEB/MOCK_DATA.json',
     function(data){
         var tr;
         $.each (data, function (key, val) {
            tr = $('<tr/>');
            tr.append('<td class="name" rel="' + val.first_name + '">' + val.first_name + '</td>');
            tr.append('<td ><input class="metric1"/>' + '</td>');
            tr.append('<td class="metric2" >' + val.id + '</td>');
            tr.append('<td class="metric3"><span class="multTotal">' +'0.00'+ '</span></td>');
     tr.append('<td class="metric3-100"><span class="metric3-100">' +'0.00'+ '</span></td>');
     tr.append('<td class="metric1-100"><span class="metric1-100">' +'0.00'+ '</span></td>');
            $('table').append(tr);
         });

         $.each (data, function (key, val) {
            li = $('<li/>');
            li.append('<input rel="name" type="checkbox" value="' + val.first_name + '"><label for="cb1">' + val.first_name + '</label></li>');
            $('ul').append(li);
         });

       $("input").keyup(multInputs);
       });

$("input:checkbox").click(function () {
    var showAll = true;
    $('tr').not('.first').hide();
    $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
        if ($(this)[0].checked) {
            showAll = false;
            var dimension1= $(this).attr('rel');
            var value = $(this).val();            
            $('td.' + dimension1+ '[rel="' + value + '"]').parent('tr').show();
        }
    });
    if(showAll){
        $('tr').show();
    }
});
```

```css
h1{
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
table{
  width:100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
.tbl-header{
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
 }
.tbl-content{
  height:300px;
  overflow-x:auto;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

th{
  padding: 20px 15px;
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
td{
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align:middle;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #fff;

}

tr:nth-child(odd) td {
  background:#2cc3ce;
  color:#0d3852;
}

/* demo styles */

@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,500,300,700);
body{
  background: #0d3852;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
section{
  margin: 50px;
}

input {
max-width:50px;
}

*,
*:after,
*::before {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.ac-custom {
 padding: 0 1em;
 max-width: 900px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

.ac-custom h2 {
 font-size: 1em;
 font-weight: 300;
 padding: 0 0 0.5em;
 margin: 0 0 30px;
 color:#0d3852;
}

.ac-custom ul,
.ac-custom ol {
 list-style: none;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0 auto;
 max-width: 800px;
}

.ac-custom li {
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 0.5em 0;
 position: relative;
}

.ac-custom label {
 display: inline-block;
 position: relative;
 font-size: 1em;
 padding: 0 0 0 80px;
 vertical-align: top;
 color: #0d3852;
 cursor: pointer;
 -webkit-transition: color 0.3s;
 transition: color 0.3s;
}

.ac-custom input[type="checkbox"],
.ac-custom input[type="radio"],
.ac-custom label::before {
 width: 20px;
 height: 20px;
 top: 50%;
 left: 0;
 margin-top: -12px;
 position: absolute;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.ac-custom input[type="checkbox"],
.ac-custom input[type="radio"] {
 opacity: 0;
 -webkit-appearance: none;
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: middle;
 z-index: 100;
}

.ac-custom label::before {
 content: '';
 border: 1px solid #0d3852;
 -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s;
 transition: opacity 0.3s;
}

.ac-radio label::before {
 border-radius: 50%;
}

.ac-custom input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label,
.ac-custom input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
 color: #fff;
} 

.ac-custom input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label::before,
.ac-custom input[type="radio"]:checked + label::before {
 opacity: 0.8;
}

/* General SVG and path styles */

.ac-custom svg {
 position: absolute;
 width: 20px;
 height: 20px;
 top: 50%;
 margin-top: -12px;
 left: 0px;
 pointer-events: none;
}

.ac-custom svg path {
 stroke: #0d3852;
 stroke-width: 13px;
 stroke-linecap: round;
 stroke-linejoin: round;
 fill: none;
}

/* Specific input, SVG and path styles */

/* Circle */
.ac-circle input[type="checkbox"],
.ac-circle input[type="radio"],
.ac-circle label::before {
 width: 30px;
 height: 30px;
 margin-top: -15px;
 left: 10px;
 position: absolute;
}

.ac-circle label::before {
 background-color: #fff;
 border: none;
}

.ac-circle svg {
 width: 70px;
 height: 70px;
 margin-top: -35px;
 left: -10px;
}

.ac-circle svg path {
 stroke-width: 5px;
} 

/* Box Fill */
.ac-boxfill svg path {
 stroke-width: 8px;
} 

/* Swirl */
.ac-swirl svg path {
 stroke-width: 8px;
}

/* List */
.ac-list ol {
 list-style: decimal;
 list-style-position: inside;
}

.ac-list ol li {
 font-size: 2em;
 padding: 1em 1em 0 2em;
 text-indent: -40px;
}

.ac-list ol li label {
 font-size: 0.5em;
 text-indent: 0;
 padding-left: 30px;
}

.ac-list label::before {
 display: none;
}

.ac-list svg {
 width: 100%;
 height: 80px;
 left: 0;
 top: 1.2em;
 margin-top: 0px;
}

.ac-list svg path {
 stroke-width: 4px;
}

.row {
  margin-left: -15px;
  margin-right: -15px;
  margin-top:0;
}
.col-sm-4 {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 1px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .col-sm-4 {
    float: left;
  }

  .col-sm-4 {
    width: 33.33333333%;
  } 
 
 .filter-columns {
 background-color:#2cc3ce;
 }
 
 .filter-columns-alt {
 background-color:#78D9E0;
 min-height:256px;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/svgcheckbx.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="js/allinone.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-4 filter-columns">
   <div class="ac-custom ac-checkbox ac-cross" autocomplete="off">
    <h2>Dimension1</h2>
    <ul>
     <li><input rel="name" type="checkbox" value="Debra"><label for="cb1">Debra</label></li>
     <li><input rel="name" type="checkbox" value="Julie"><label for="cb1">Julie</label></li>
     <li><input rel="name" type="checkbox" value="Norma"><label for="cb1">Norma</label></li>
     <li><input rel="name" type="checkbox" value="Bobby"><label for="cb1">Bobby</label></li>
     <li><input rel="name" type="checkbox" value="Henry"><label for="cb1">Henry</label></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
  </div>
  
  <div id="body">
    

<table>
    <tr id="ProductID" class="first">
        <th>NAME</th>
        <th>INPUT</th>
        <th>MAIN VALUE</th>
        <th>DIFF</th>
 <th>DIFF /100</th>
        <th>MV /100</th>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

**05)** The filter works if I put static data into it.

So, in the HTML code, in the filter section I put this :

```
<ul>
    <li><input rel="name" type="checkbox" value="Debra"><label for="cb1">Debra</label></li>
    <li><input rel="name" type="checkbox" value="Julie"><label for="cb1">Julie</label></li>
    <li><input rel="name" type="checkbox" value="Norma"><label for="cb1">Norma</label></li>
    <li><input rel="name" type="checkbox" value="Bobby"><label for="cb1">Bobby</label></li>
    <li><input rel="name" type="checkbox" value="Henry"><label for="cb1">Henry</label></li>
</ul>
```

and then the filter works fine. I am guessing the problem is in the JS code.
I guess in the first function where I load the JSON data I have to replace this line in order to trigger the second function :

[image]

***UPD*** : The code is show below :

```
$.getJSON(
     'http://apolosiskos.co.uk/TEB/MOCK_DATA.json',
     function(data){
         var tr;
         $.each (data, function (key, val) {
            tr = $('<tr/>');
            tr.append('<td class="name" rel="' + val.first_name + '">' + val.first_name + '</td>');
            tr.append('<td ><input class="metric1"/>' + '</td>');
            tr.append('<td class="metric2" >' + val.id + '</td>');
            tr.append('<td class="metric3"><span class="multTotal">' +'0.00'+ '</span></td>');
        tr.append('<td class="metric3-100"><span class="metric3-100">' +'0.00'+ '</span></td>');
        tr.append('<td class="metric1-100"><span class="metric1-100">' +'0.00'+ '</span></td>');
            $('table').append(tr);
         });

         $.each (data, function (key, val) {
            li = $('<li/>');
            li.append('<input rel="name" type="checkbox" value="' + val.first_name + '"><label for="cb1">' + val.first_name + '</label></li>');
            $('ul').append(li);
         });
       });

$('body').on('input', 'input:checkbox', filters);

function filters(){
    var showAll = true;
    $('tr').not('.first').hide();
    $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
        if ($(this)[0].checked) {
            showAll = false;
            var dimension1= $(this).attr('rel');
            var value = $(this).val();            
            $('td.' + dimension1+ '[rel="' + value + '"]').parent('tr').show();
        }
    });
    if(showAll){
        $('tr').show();
    }
};

$("input:checkbox").click(filters);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use event delegation `on()` to track new inputs added dynamicaly to the DOM :

```
$('body').on('keyup', 'input', multInputs);
```

You can also use `input` event it's better :

```
$('body').on('input', 'input', multInputs);
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: It did not work. I pasted the code at the end of my question to see the changes I made.

Comment: Here is the link : apolosiskos.co.uk/TEB/js/allinone.js I tried to put a name in the click function and then I added your line in the first function (JSON loader)

Comment: the first input is the _event_ not _field_ so replace `$('body').on('input:checkbox', 'input:checkbox', filters);` by `$('body').on('input', 'input:checkbox', filters);` and put it out of the getJson

Comment: I updated the code. I have the first function that load the JSON data, then the event and then the function. It is a click function so in order to put a name, I had the change the JS syntax. Maybe that causes the problem. It does not work at the moment.

Comment: Please try to replace `$("input:checkbox").click(function filters() {` by `$('bidy').on('click','input:checkbox', function filters() {`